# Excel - using the name of the file (stored in a cell) to reference values from that file

Tags: excel

in B1 cell I have a reference to a value stored in some other Excel file:

`='C:\podatki\Finance\Sp\Predloge\[L2019-1.xlsx]List1'!$A$4`

The name of the file is "L2019-1.xlsx".

I would like to use A column for list of files: A1 for the first name, A2 for the second, etc...) and I would like to have B column with references to the files in the A column.

For instance, if A1 cell is "Xfiles.xlsx" then B1 would be:

`='C:\podatki\Finance\Sp\Predloge\[Xfiles.xlsx]List1'!$A$4`

Which formula should I put inside [] part of the path to always get the correct name of the file (from A column)?

Thank you.

Comment: Find and replace?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you still want to get the value from cell `A4` in `L2019-1.xlsx` (and not just the reference string), correct? In this case, simply building up the reference string based on the file name in A1 will just give you a string, but not the value from `A4` in `L2019-1.xlsx`.
You must put your reference string into the `INDIRECT` function to make it work.

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\podatki\Finance\Sp\Predloge\["&A1&"]Sheet1'!$A$4")
```

Be aware that `INDIRECT` is a **volatile** function, so excessive use of it might slow down your calculation.

In order for that solution to work, the file you are referencing to (`L2019-1.xlsx`) must be open.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not working. It returns an error.
Even when I changed the content of A1 cell to L2019-1.xlsx - so I've added the file extension.

Comment: @user3549668 Which error does it return? Probably a #REF error? I forgot to mention that your file L2019-1.xlsx must be open in order for that to work (the error will also re-appear once you close L2019-1.xlsx again - that's because INDIRECT is volatile and recalculates anytime you change something in your sheet).

Comment: Yes, that was it. So all the files must be open. Thank you.